# Rails 4 caching template in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, assets, production

my situation is this. Create a Web application on my local machine in Rails 4. Works fine in development mode, unless in production also had to compile the assets files. And when I upload to my hosting entire folder, the first time it worked fine but when I edit files I do not see myself reflected. Delete everything and went back up but I still see the templates hsoting previous version. I'm seeing something that no longer exists ... Any ideas?

Comment: welcome to SO. You need to provide some more info and code here. we are coders not oracles :-)

Comment: did you restart your application after uploading new code?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the documentation of the [rails asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html):

> Capistrano (v2.15.1 and above) includes a recipe to handle this in
> deployment. Add the following line to Capfile:
>
> ```
> load 'deploy/assets'
> ```

If you do not use [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com) for your deployment you should give it at try.